# Start server from terminal using a script

Tags: ubuntu

I've a server "**nodejs server.js**" and I want it to restart as soon as  it crashes but only if previous restart time is more than a second. This will prevent my email being flooded if the server exits immediately.

Here is the `start_server.sh` which restarts it. I've placed it in `@reboot` in crontab and it starts quite fine when the server boots.

But how can I run `start_server.sh` from the terminal and close the terminal later and it should work just fine without exiting?

I've tried `nohup start_server.sh` but that does not work. I also want to redirect the STDOUT to a log file.

start_server.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
count=0

while :
do
if test $count -lt 40
then
mail -s "server.js started just now" myemail@gmail.com  < /dev/null
fi

count=`expr $count + 1`

date1=`date +%s`  #get unix time

cd /home/login/railways/nodejs

echo "Starting time is $date1"
 /usr/bin/nodejs server.js >> server.log

date2=`date +%s`  #get unix time


if test $date1 -eq $date2
then
        msg="exiting as process has failed"
        echo $msg
        if test $count -lt 40
        then
        mail -s $msg  myemail@gmail.com  < /dev/null
        fi
        sleep 10
fi


echo "restarting the process"


sleep 1
done
```

Comment: `nohup start_server.sh`  should work actually if your script works fine (I haven't checked). But you can always try to run the script inside a `screen` or `tmux` session, detach and log off. This way, you will also see errors when you reattach.

Comment: Why aren't you using Upstart (or systemd, as the case may be), to run your service?

Comment: @muru because due to bugs it's crashing frequently and I'd regularly need to start it from cmdline in the middle of day.